# html and css margin auto error

Tags: html, css

I have a container div with the class banner. In my css the following rule does not centre the banner.

Why is this?

```
.banner {
    width:900px;
    height:300px;
    margin:0 auto;
    background:url('img/banner-bg.jpg') top left no-repeat;
    border-radius: 20px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
    -o-border-radius: 20px;
    -moz-border-radius: 20px;
}
```

This is the HTML code, i can't see anything wrong with it

```
       <!DOCTYPE html>
       <html>
      <head>
  <title>Animated Banner CSS</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="banner.css">
     </head>
      <body>

         <div class="banner"> 

       <img class="img-snow01" src="img/snow-back.png" width="900" height="600">
       <img src="img/foreground.png" width="335" height="1000" class="img01">
       <img class="img-snow02" src="img/snow-front.png" width="900" height="600">

            <h3 class="txt-heading01">Everthing is 30% off</h3>
       <!--<h3 class="txt-heading02"> Friday and Saturday</h3>-->
        <p class="txt01">Winter</p>
       <p class="txt02">Sale</p>
      <!---<p class="txt03">Click here</p>
       <p class="txt04"> to learn more</p>
         -->

      </div> <!-- Banner-->


       </body>
      </html>
```

Comment: can you post the relevant html code as well?

Comment: its working fine here [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/J7Tda/1/)

Comment: Your problem is not in this code... some other html elements/css rules causing it, so post complete html/css of page....

Comment: updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/J7Tda/3/

Answer (score 0):

For `margin: 0 auto;` to trigger a 'center align', it requires the element to **have a width set**. because `display: block` elements will always be set at 100% width by default

It is also common to set `text-align:center` on the parent element *(in the case of the child elements being of CSS display type: `inline`*)

```
 /* optional if child elements are display type of inline */
body { text-align: center; } 

/* set a width */
.page {
   width: 80%; margin: 0 auto; text-align: left;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/bBsLm/1/

Comment: Thanks for the edit @edwoolard - I had a typo in the demo too - updated : http://jsfiddle.net/bBsLm/2/